# Vertical space between glossary entries

Tags: glossaries

Is there a way to increase (well add, right now there seems to be hardly any) the vertical space between glossary entries without making a custom style, if so how? Had a quick run through the user manual but did not find anything in between all entries, not just for groups or changing the heading or...

I am using

```
\printglossary[type=person, nonumberlist=false, style=index]
```

for very long entries with long multiline descriptions. So if there is a solution that depends on something the would not work with multiple columns, rely on adding a paragraph after the entry or something like that -- all would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{<vertical space>}` to add vertical space between the items listed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\medskip} % add space after each item

\newglossaryentry{Blackbox1}
{
    name=Blackbox models 1,
    sort=blackbox,
    description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Blackbox2}
{
    name=Blackbox models 2,
    sort=blackbox,
    description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Blackbox3}
{
    name=Blackbox models 3,
    sort=blackbox,
    description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques.}
}

\begin{document}
    
\glsaddall

\printglossary[nonumberlist=false, style=index] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That will certainly be the/a answer. If I have multiple glossaries where do I need to renewcommand to change it back and forth? I am currently trying but the first like ten tries for places that seem to make sense to me always set it to one spacing for all glossaries.

Comment: I was a little overexcited as my test document was to short. As the name indicates this adds the space after the description line. This works great if the page numbers don't extend over the line break. If they do the space appears in between numbers as I only noted once doing the change for the real book. So I guess the question becomes is there something like \glspostnumbers doing the same thing.

Comment: Your (Simon Dispa) answer allowed for a more effective secons quick-reading of the manual and made me realize I should use different kinds of styles. I am good with using altlist now for the encyclopedia-style one and the rest worked already. Thanks.

Comment: @Erik Itter Thank you for your feedback! Now you understand why it is better to ask a question including a minimum, but complete, testing code, so help will be faster and more beneficial.